# Windows 11 Ubuntu WSL2 - Autostarting services with /etc/wsl.conf doesn't work

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-11

I'm attempting to start docker and postgresql automatically with my ubuntu wsl2 instance. I read about the /etc/wsl.conf configuration file and it only starts one service, not two. For example if I have:

```
[boot]
command = service docker start
```

and restart wsl.. I get the following:

```
mryan ~ $service docker status
* Docker is not running
mryan ~ $service postgresql status
12/main (port 5432): online
```

Again, if I remove the last line from etc/wsl.conf and restart wsl. Docker starts just fine. I've also tried quotes around the commands as in command="service docker start" but it didn't make a difference. Is there some format error I'm making here? Any help would be appreciated. I can get around this by manually starting services but it would be nice to make things work properly!

Comment: You seem to be trying to run services via systemd on WSL. Ubuntu on WSL does not use systemd (at least systemd isn't pid 1), so you can't use it to run services like you would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try combining the commands into a single line maybe, with `&&`.

One still can start it on demand, eg. with `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
RUNNING=`ps aux | grep dockerd | grep -v grep`
if [ -z "$RUNNING" ]; then
    sudo dockerd > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    disown
fi
```

This may require group `docker`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```